# Doing something in case process forcefully closes

Tags: python, python-2.7, terminate

I've got this next section of code:

```
try:
    import pythoncom
except:
    os.system("pip install pypiwin32")
    import pythoncom
    installed = True
```

Now, I want the program to uninstall pypiwin32 in case it imported it itself. (if installed is set to True, uninstall pypiwin32 when program terminates)

my problem is, people can close the program by pressing X, by going to windows task manager, or by pc shutting down.

even if those things do occur, I want to uninstall pypiwin32 in case it wasn't installed prior to the app. how can I do that? how can I catch an unexpected fail of the program, or close, or ANYTHING pretty much, and work on last things before it closes? is it even possible?

edit: I know this will only work on windows, I know it is very occasional. that is how it's supposed to be. but the solution 'should' be platform-wide (I think?)

Comment: when a process is killed (-9 on unix or just with Windows task manager) the killed process doesn't get a warning. so no you cannot.

Comment: Did you have a look at or consider using [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) instead?

Comment: Why do you want to uninstall pypiwin32, what's the rationale behind that?

Comment: If my program installs it, I want to uninstall it once I'm finish.